# Save an image stored in the resources/drawable folder inot the gallery

Tags: android, image, save, gallery

I have an image button. When the user clicks on the button, I want to save an image stored in the resources/drawable folder into the gallery of the phone/tablet.

I cannot figure this out! I am a beginning android programmer and I have researched for hours on how to do this. However, I do not understand the many websites that post code without any explanation. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Get image bitamp :

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Store bitamp on given path :

```
File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "ic_launcher.png");
outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```